# How to add Bottom Padding in Page View in Flutter

Tags: flutter, padding, flutter-pageview

I want to add bottom padding for showing page in page view like this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m67Cx.jpg).

Answer (score 1):

Put your page in a `Padding` element and then set edge insets only for bottom:

```
new Padding(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 20),
    child: *Active Page View Here*
),
```

Comment: i want add  padding to active page not all page

Comment: Then in that case, replace child with the component that is active (similar to the image provided in the question).

Comment: how to detect active page

Comment: That will depend on how you've programmed your application and how you manage all these page views. It may be possible to maintain a variable (boolean) for each page view that becomes true when that page becomes active ... and then use conditional code in Flutter to detect and add Padding automatically.

Comment: if I add padding to it,all pages will have padding and I just want it on my active page and the left and right pages shouldn't have alternation.I want those to stay in that case that they were.

Comment: Yeah I understand. To solve this, you should maintain a variable like `isActive` for each page and then only add padding if `isActive` is `true`. This way, only the active page will have padding.